# what is the error of this staircase problem in Hacker Rank?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

# Complete the staircase function below.
def staircase(n):
    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(0,n):
            if (i + j >= n):
                print("#",end='') 
            else:
                print(" ",end='')
        print("\r")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())

    staircase(n)
```

Sample input: 4

Sample output:

```
   #
  ##
 ###
####
```

This says there is ***Out Of List*** error. How do I have to solve it?

Comment: Error = Out of list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `for-loop` and each iteration print `one-space` and `one-sharp` base each iteration:
One line:

```
n = 5
print(*[' '*(n-i) + '#'*i for i in range(1,n)], sep='\n')
```

Expand version:

```
def prnt_shrp(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        print(' '*(n-i) + '#'*i)
```

Output:

```
>>> prnt_shrp(5)
    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####
```

Explanation:

```
>>> '#'*3
'###'
```

Answer (score 2):

Python is very popular because of its flexibility as you can see from the code we just run the loop n times to solve this problem following are the explanation of every steps:-

1. We run a for loop in python using range function like range(1, n+1) this will give use values from [1,2,3..n] now loop run for n times from 1 to n
2. Now we print space because we want to create a invert triangle like :-

for this we need to print space n - i times and print # i times. to do that
we use print(" " * (n - i) + "#" * i). Python is very flexible so we can do
things like that.

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

# Complete the staircase function below.
def staircase(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(" "* (n - i) + "#" * (i))

n = 4

staircase(n)
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly. - [from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32044162)